# ssl for both site and tomcat

Tags: ssl, tomcat

I have a domain http://www.example.com

I will add to it a tomcat endpoint https://www.example.com/mywar

Now I want to add SSL for both. I understood from my hoster that the SSL for the domain can be configured only after I will change the nameservers to the hoster and tell them to update the a record.

What about the tomcat endpoint? Will defining SSL to my site/domain https://www.example.com make the tomcat endpoint ssl-wise as well?

If not, what other steps should be done to make it happen?

Thanks

Comment: How do you serve https://www.example.com? Through Tomcat, too? Your nameservers have nothing to do with it. Your domain ist hosted by you on the servername www.example.com, the protocol (HTTP, HTTPS, FTP, SCP, whatever) is controlled by the underlying application.

Comment: example.com is a "simple" site with html and php. The domain's nameservers are pointing to host X. Host y told me I need to change the nameservers to host y before applying the ssl.

Comment: In this case you'll need something like a reverse proxy (e. g. nginx) which acts as TLS endpoint and redirects your clients to either the Tomcat host (https://www.example.com/mywar) or the PHP site (http://www.example.com) or serves the PHP site directly

Comment: if a user enters to https://www.example.com it will go to the site, it the url is https://www.example.com/mywar it will point to the tomcat, my question is about the SSL of the tomcat. is it enough to SSL the domain or do I need to do something on the tomcat side?